# Unable to merge the data from two tables

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables, the first one contain all the records and second table contains few records, i am trying to put left join to get all the records of first table and data columns of the records that matches in the second table.

**Table A**

```
id_step|id_workflow|id_action|
-------+-----------+---------+
      1|          1|       11|
      6|          1|       11|
      7|          1|       11|
      8|          1|       12|
      9|          1|       12|
     10|          1|       12|
```

**Table B**

```
id_step|id_client|id_process|id_workflow|is_approved|action_by|action_date|
-------+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+
      1|    10680|        10|          1|true       |         |           |
```

I am looking to get the below result
**Expected Output**

```
id_step|id_client|id_workflow|id_action|is_approved|action_by|action_date|
-------+---------+---------- +---------+-----------+---------+-----------+
      1|    10680|          1|       11|true       |         |           |
      6|    10680|          1|       11|pending    |         |           |
      7|    10680|          1|       11|pending    |         |           |
      8|    10680|          1|       11|pending    |         |           |
      9|    10680|          1|       11|pending    |         |           |
     10|    10680|          1|       11|pending    |         |           |
```

I did try query

```
select 
x.id_step,
y.id_client,
x.id_workflow,
x.id_action, 
(case when y.is_approved is null then 'pending' else y.is_approved::text end ) as is_approved,
y.action_date,
y.action_by 
from nw_adsys_wfx_config as x 
left join nw_adsys_cli_wfx_process as y 
on x.id_step = y.id_step 
where x.id_workflow = 1
and y.id_process = 10
```

but i am getting this output

```
id_step|id_client|id_workflow|id_action|is_approved|action_date|action_by|
-------+---------+-----------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+
      1|    10680|          1|       11|true       |           |         |
```

Comment: I removed the tags for all the unsupported Postgres versions. If you need a solution for a specific version, then please add only one tag for that version

Answer (score 1):

The query contains a left join but also a `where` condition on both tables which breaks the intend of the left join.

Instead, you can move the condition to the join

```sql
...
from nw_adsys_wfx_config as x 
left join nw_adsys_cli_wfx_process as y 
  on x.id_step = y.id_step 
     AND y.id_process = 10
where x.id_workflow = 1
```